# Proper way of using Bouncy Castle with Android

Tags: android, gradle, cryptography, bouncycastle, android-multidex

I need to use Bouncy Castle with android (specifically for ECDHE). I included Bouncy Castle as a dependency in my gradle project file following: [How to add Bouncy Castle algorithm to Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584401/how-to-add-bouncy-castle-algorithm-to-android)
I got the following error on compilation:

`Error while merging dex archives: The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.`

Going through this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex
I found that multidex apps can have efficiency and security issues.

I then decided to manually add the needed classes from the library to my project as advised here: [Using Bouncy Castle library causes massive increase in output .jar file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981606/using-bouncy-castle-library-causes-massive-increase-in-output-jar-file-size).
This, however got too tedious.

Is there a better way to achieve what I need?

Comment: Doesn't your IDE provide some kind of automation for it?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I am using Android Studio. I am not aware of any automation available for this use case. So far, I’ve tried to copy the class files that I need, but each of them in turn use several other classes.

Comment: I've tried to read through it, but I don't see security issues mentioned on the page you linked to, and for efficiency: I'd just test to see if it is an issue in the first place. Note that BC is a software only provider, and not a particularly well tested one IMHO. So if you can avoid using it altogether... You could maybe also try the FIPS provider if it fits your need, it would remove a lot of code I suppose.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I decided to go with Bouncy castle enabling multidex for now. So far I don't see an efficiency issue except a slightly bigger apk size. I'll checkout the FIPS provider. Thanks!